# How can I print out my PHP variables in the html code properly?

Tags: php, html

How do I use my `$url` and `$name` variables as values in the html code, because right now they are just the strings `$url` and $name?

```
$curnp = $_COOKIE["username"];
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT clientname FROM npclients WHERE npname='$curnp'");
$data = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($data as $name): 
    $url = "http://www.dev.healthfullu.com/clients.php?name=".urlencode($name);
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<div class="news-item-detail"><a href="$url" class="news-item-title" target="_blank">$name</a>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</li>';
endforeach ?>
```

Comment: `'Con'.$cat.'enate'` your values.

Comment: How do i do that? I am really new to PHP. Sorry that I'm asking you this directly, but would you be able to edit my post to show me how to do that?

Comment: I thought I was being clever, showing you how to do it right within my comment. Too clever, I guess...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I was quite amused ;)

Comment: Ohhhh, lol i see, sorry :/

Comment: It's okay, we were all new once, but when you ask for help it's a good idea to pay attention to what you're given ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
echo '<div class="news-item-detail"><a href="$url" class="news-item-title" target="_blank">$name</a>';
```

to either:

```
echo "<div class='news-item-detail'><a href='$url' class='news-item-title' target='_blank'>$name</a>";
```

or

```
echo '<div class="news-item-detail"><a href=' . $url . ' class="news-item-title" target="_blank">' . $name . '</a>';
```

And read the difference about quote styles and strings at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Please teach Best Practice methods instead of showing them all that short form coding methods that make them sloppy coders.

Comment: @user3911017 In other words, variables can't be echo'ed properly inside single quoted echos, unless "concatenated". Concatenates are dots (a chaining method if I could say). You can echo variables when the echo is wrapped in double quotes and without having to concatenate. Both examples show you the differences. However, if double quotes are required, the the `"` inside the echo needs to be escaped using \ as in `\"`

Comment: @user3911017 You're very much welcome. - Edit: Typo `the the " inside...` should have read as `then the " inside...` - Bad bad keyboard.